# Excel Text Content Extraction Returns Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am using a text extractor for Excel. The xlsx file has just 1 sheet. But I find in the extracted text a creator's name--not found in the Sheet1--along with data from Sheet1. The extracted text has 3 sections.

```
<creator and some data>
"Sheet1"
<actual data>
```

Presently I am skipping all the lines  until the string "Sheet1" is found.

I am curious to find out what the First Section  is about.

Thanks

Comment: I am sure there is a question hidden somewhere in this post. Can you help me find it or is this a quiz where one has to solve the riddle (of finding the question) first before he / she is entitled to answer it? Or am I just blind and don't see it?

Comment: Did you ever use a text extractor for Excel? If so, then you won't have difficulty in understanding the issue. Anyway, in the extracted text, I am finding 2 data sections inter-leaved by the string "Sheet1". It is not clear to me what the 1st data section is. Is Excel hiding the file creator and some random data from appearing in the edit screen? Is it possible to suppress this data? Is it possible that this depends on the extractor one uses?  I am currently using XSSF-POI extractor in Java. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think I found the answer. There is a "hidden" sheet in the xlsx file. The Section#1 outlined in the question contains the text content of the hidden sheet. By the way, I was able to figure out the hidden stuff in Excel editor, by clicking File->Check for Issues(button attached to "Prepare for Sharing")